# ScrollView в GridViewPager блокирует onSwipeListener

Tags: android, android-scrollview, android-wear

В своем GridViewPager  я пытаюсь разместить элемент со ScrollView. Пролистывание в самом GridViewPager  я запретил, повесил на него onSwipeListener им же перемещаюсь и отлавливаю перемещение между разными элементами сетки. Проблема заключается в том, что при попадании на элемент сетки со скроллом - swipe перестает работать.
Меня интересует, как бы можно было сделать прокрутку и сохранить при этом работоспособность onSwipeListener.

вот код разметки, слушателя  и адаптера, если нужен еще какой то код - я добавлю.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorBlack"
    >


       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/textView_count"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
           android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
           android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
           android:gravity="center_horizontal"
           android:text="1 из 10"
           android:textColor="@color/colorWhite" />

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/textView_example_one"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_below="@id/textView_learn_bottom_count"
           android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
           android:layout_marginLeft="27dp"
           android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
           android:text="Custom text"
           android:textColor="@color/colorWhite" />

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/textView_example_two"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_below="@+id/textView_example_one"
           android:layout_marginLeft="27dp"
           android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
           android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
           android:text="Custom text"
           android:textColor="@color/colorWhite" />
</ScrollView>
```

**onSwipeListener.java**

```
public class OnSwipeTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {

    private final GestureDetector gestureDetector;

    public OnSwipeTouchListener (Context ctx){
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(ctx, new GestureListener());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    private final class GestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

        private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 100;
        private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;


        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            boolean result = false;
            try {
                float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
                float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
                if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
                    if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                        if (diffX > 0) {
                            onSwipeRight();
                        } else {
                            onSwipeLeft();
                        }
                    }
                    result = true;
                }
                else if (Math.abs(diffY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                    if (diffY > 0) {
                        onSwipeBottom();
                    } else {
                        onSwipeTop();
                    }
                }
                result = true;

            } catch (Exception exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
            return result;
        }
    }

    public void onSwipeRight() {
    }

    public void onSwipeLeft() {
    }

    public void onSwipeTop() {
    }

    public void onSwipeBottom() {
    }
}
```

**MyGridAdapter.java**

```
 public class MyGridAdapter extends GridPagerAdapter {

        final Context mContext;

        public MyGridAdapter(final Context context) {
            mContext = context;
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(final ViewGroup viewGroup, final int row, final int col) {

             BottomLayout rootView = new BottomLayout(mContext);

            viewGroup.addView(rootView);
            return rootView;

        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount(int i) {
            return List.size();
        }


        @Override
        public int getCurrentColumnForRow(int row, int currentColumn) {
            return currentColumn;
        }


        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i, int i2, Object o) {
            viewGroup.removeView((View) o);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object o) {
            return view.equals(o);
        }

    }
```

**UDT:**

**MyActvity.java**

```
 public class MynActivity extends WearableActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.grid_layout);

    initPagerAdapterAndListener();
}


private void initPagerAdapterAndListener() {

    pager.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(MyActivity.this) {

        public void onSwipeTop() {
            pager.setCurrentItem(1, mColCounter);
        }

        public void onSwipeRight() {
            if (mColCounter <= mList.size()) {
                mColCounter--;
                pager.setCurrentItem(0, mColCounter);
            }
        }

        public void onSwipeLeft() {
            if (mColCounter >= 0 && mColCounter != mList.size()) {
                mColCounter++;
                pager.setCurrentItem(0, mColCounter);
            }

        }

        public void onSwipeBottom() {
            pager.setCurrentItem(0, mColCounter);
        }
    });

    pager.setPagingEnabled(false); //EnableScrolling
    pager.setAdapter(new MyActivity.MyGridAdapter(this));

    DotsPageIndicator dotsPageIndicator = (DotsPageIndicator) findViewById(R.id.page_indicator);
    dotsPageIndicator.setPager(pager);
}
```

**MyGridViewPager.java**

```
public class MyGridViewPager extends GridViewPager {

    private boolean isPagingEnabled = true;

    public MyGridViewPager(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyGridViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        return this.isPagingEnabled && super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        return this.isPagingEnabled && super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
    }

    public void setPagingEnabled(boolean b) {
        this.isPagingEnabled = b;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

> In the following snippet, a return value of true from the individual on methods indicates that you have handled the touch event. A return value of false passes events down through the view stack until the touch has been successfully handled.

Получается, onFling даже не начинал работу.

```
    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {return false;}
```

Comment: у меня щас нету возможности протестить на устройстве, но я правильно вас понял, заменив возвращаемое значение в методе onDown на false  - это решит мою проблему?

Comment: Это как минимум активирует onFling, а дальше решаем проблемы по мере поступления, если не решит нужно смотреть дальше, пока это очевидно и это нужно знать в первую очередь работая с классом GestureListener

Comment: установив значение false вообще перестал работать листенер!

Comment: значит проблема в том коде который вы не показываете, а точней там где onSwipeListener.java используете.

Comment: добавил кода  в вопрос

Comment: Многовато остается неизвестного, сложновато для меня сходу понять, в чем проблема здесь. Здесь нужна магия - я слаб)

Comment: может вы знаете, по какой причине если я вместо свайп истенера вешаю  pager.setOnPageChangeListener() то он не работает? Его методы просто не реагируют